# How can i assign the value of html div to a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to  show online and offline users in php for all time zones, how can i go about it, initially I am getting the pc time in JavaScript and I am trying to return the value  to an html .

Now I want to know how I can assign the div contents to a php string. How can i go about it?

Then after that I will use the
If ($users_last_activity = $users_time)
(
Echo "online";
)
Else
( 
Echo "offline";
)
(N:b when the user is offline the JavaScript code stop reading so it's no longer equal to last activity. The last activity auto refresh in the database. The last activity also stops when user is offline but it saved in database and users time is not, just want to save it in a variable)

To know the online and offline users the user last activity is in my database already.

Help me out, if there is also any other suggestion on how to know the offline and online users in my website, or to assign the content of html  to php variable  $users_time.

Comment: Php is a server side language and html+javascript is client side language. when any request made it executed at server side and the response in html+javascript so you can assign Php value to javascript variable but it is not possible to assign html div to php variable.

Comment: please try to share some cod of an example about what you are trying to do. your question without the code is too ambiguous.

Comment: I am asking with phone can't share pls, but can I assign a JavaScript variable to a php viarable?

Comment: If not then can anyone suggest for on how to go about it, show offline and offline users.

Comment: you can't assign Javascript variable to a php variable, use ajax to send the Javascript variable to the server side, thus you can assign it to php variable.

Comment: Don't really know how to do that can you help me with some codez